# wpa_supplicant debug messages

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to connect to a wifi network from a Raspberry Pi 3 (running Raspbian Wheezy) using `wpa_supplicant` commands being called through Python scripts. The connection is happening but I am observing random disconnections from wifi, which is resulting in the loss of vital data being failed to upload. I tried debugging the `wpa_supplicant` into the log files and I am getting some debug messages which I cant understand. Also, I'm not sure also if its related to the disconnections or not.

**Command:**

```
wpa_supplicant -s -B -d -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

**Not understood debug messages:**

```
Sep 21 07:16:09 159170608123159978265 wpa_supplicant[2864]: nl80211: Ignore RTM_NEWLINK event for foreign ifindex 556
Sep 21 07:16:09 159170608123159978265 wpa_supplicant[1561]: nl80211: Ignore RTM_NEWLINK event for foreign ifindex 556
Sep 21 07:16:09 159170608123159978265 wpa_supplicant[2864]: nl80211: Ignore RTM_DELLINK event for foreign ifindex 555
Sep 21 07:16:09 159170608123159978265 wpa_supplicant[1561]: nl80211: Ignore RTM_DELLINK event for foreign ifindex 555
Sep 21 07:16:09 159170608123159978265 wpa_supplicant[2864]: nl80211: Ignore RTM_NEWLINK event for foreign ifindex 556
Sep 21 07:16:09 159170608123159978265 wpa_supplicant[1561]: nl80211: Ignore RTM_NEWLINK event for foreign ifindex 556
Sep 21 07:16:09 159170608123159978265 wpa_supplicant[1561]: nl80211: Ignore RTM_NEWLINK event for foreign ifindex 556
Sep 21 07:16:09 159170608123159978265 wpa_supplicant[2864]: nl80211: Ignore RTM_NEWLINK event for foreign ifindex 556
```